# travis-ci: matrix.exclude ignored?

Tags: travis-ci

i'm setting up travis-ci form my C++-project, and want to have three different jobs per build:

- linux (native=64bit)
- osx/64bit (native)
- osx/32bit

to achieve this, i've configure travis to build on `linux` and `osx`, and created an evironment-variable `ARCH` that is set either to a specific architecture (e.g. `i386`) or empty (for native builds)

here's my .travis.yml:

```
language: cpp
env:
  matrix:
  - ARCH=
  - ARCH=i386
  global:
  - secure: ...
os:
  - linux
  - osx
matrix:
  exclude:
   - os: linux
before_install:
- ./travis-ci/install-dependencies.sh
script:
- ./travis-ci/build.sh
```

the `script`- and `before_install`-scripts are setup to honour the `ARCH` envvar.

now for reasons unknown to me, when i push to github, the build-matrix includes:

- `OS:linux, env:ARCH=`
- `OS:linux, env:ARCH=i386`

and indeed, i get two jobs for linux.
so it seems that my `exclude` statement is ignored.

any hints what i should do to *not* build `linux/ARCH=i386`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the problem was, that my particular project had not had *OSX* support enabled yet (currently this needs to be done manually).
Thus the `os` axis of the matrix did not really exist.

Once the `osx` builds were enabled (and therefore the `os` axis was established properly), the `exclude` statement started to work as expected.